# Python C API Boolean Objects

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I am using Python C API 2.7.2 with my C++ console application. There is one doubt regarding Python C API Boolean Objects

I am using:

```
PyObject* myVariable = Py_True;
```

Do I need to deference myVariable with `Py_DECREF(myVariable)`?

The Python C API documentation says:-

> The Python True object. This object has no methods. It needs to be
>   treated just like any other object with respect to reference counts.

I searched the questions but could not find a clear answer for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It needs to be treated just like any other object with respect to reference counts.

This means that you **must** incref it when you take its reference

```
{
  Py_INCREF(Py_True);
  PyObject* myVariable = Py_True;
```

and you **must** decref it when you dispose of it.

```
  Py_DECREF(myVariable);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Although it isn't dynamically created, it must be reference counted because PyObject variables can hold ANY Python object. Otherwise there would need to be checks for Py_True and other special cases scattered throughout the Python runtime as well as any C/C++ code that uses the API. That would be messy and error prone.