# Does Python have pointers like c++? About Python's low-level implementation

Tags: python, implementation

I'm wondering whether python have pointers to operate. Also, I've heard that every variable even like int and strings is an object. Can anyone tell me the low-level implementation of python's variable?

I don't understand why every variable is an object. Then does it have basic, indivisible structure that is not an object?

Comment: It has a module `ctypes` for direct low-level interaction with pointers and compiled machine code functions. Generally, Python has no pointers. A variable holds a reference (usually implemented as pointer) to an object. Everything, including ints and such basic things, is an object.

Comment: Python has two things:  names and objects.  That's it.  Things like `1` and `"abc"` and `[1,2,3]` are objects.  Names can be bound to objects.  That's really the fundamentals of the "variable" system.  It's not necessarily useful to think of "variables".  A name is just something that is bound to an object.  When you supply a name as a parameter to a function, you are passing the object it is bound to, not the name.

Comment: You should also distinguish between the abstract Python language, defined by its standard documents, and a specific implementation like CPython (the most common one).

Comment: I have the feeling this is a duplicate, but I could not quickly locate a question which discusses the internal implementation of objects and references. I assume you want a beginner-friendly exposition rather than a review of the actual C code.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "yes."

The reference implementation of Python is [CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython) which is, as its name suggests, written in C. And yes, everything is an object (even integers and Booleans). In fact, the values `True` and `False` are [singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74680857/why-does-cpython-return-a-new-pointer-to-the-true-and-false-singletons-and-incre). Integer values are just objects too (the numbers -5 through, IIRC, 255 or so are singletons as well).

All Python objects consist of, at a minimum, a reference count, type metadata, and support for a doubly linked list of all objects on the heap:

```
struct _object {
    _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    PyTypeObject *ob_type;
};
```

`_PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA` is a macro used to support a doubly linked list of all heap objects. `ob_refcnt` is the reference count. `*ob_type` is type information.